# XSLFTable get size to see if it will fit in slide after insertion

Tags: apache-poi

I am working on a slide show where I insert N number of rows. There are two issues...

I don't know the number of rows, there is a max of 50 we will allow but even 50 will go out of the slide.

The text I will add to each column can also be somewhat long.

Right now, my current approach is allowing 15 rows, creating a new slide to add the next 15, and so on until I hit 50.

What I would prefer to do is get the size of the table and after I finish one row, I would like to check if it is overflowing out of the slide, and if it is, I'll remove it, make a new slide, and add it to the new table.

An alternative approach if possible, is keep the row height locked, and allow any extra text to kinda be hidden until the cell is selected (similar to an excel spreadsheet).

Answer (score 0):

Using a similar approach here

[Apache POI get Font Metrics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59713455/apache-poi-get-font-metrics)

Solution:

stringList is repopulated for each row

```
int max = 0;
int j = 0;
for (String text : stringList) {
  AttributedString attributedString = new AttributedString(text);
  attributedString.addAttribute(
      TextAttribute.FAMILY, "Avenir Book", 0, text.length());
  attributedString.addAttribute(TextAttribute.SIZE, (float)14);
  TextLayout layout = new TextLayout(attributedString.getIterator(), fontRenderContext);
  Rectangle2D bounds = layout.getBounds();
  max = Math.max(max, (int) Math.ceil((bounds.getWidth() * covertToEmu)
      / (table.getTblGrid().getGridColList().get(j).getW())));
  j++
}
```

`covertToEmu` is just a number...`bounds.getWidth()` is in 72 dpi and `table.getTblGrid().getGridColList().get(j).getW()` (the width) is in EMU. 72 dpi is just the pixels in inches...which is 72 pixels per inch. An EMU per inch is 914400.

So convertToEmu is 914400 / 72 = 12700.

The max is the number of "rows" it takes...the rest is kinda hard coded, but I split the list of data I have into sublists and add it to each slide. I know 20 rows is a good fit so if it gets higher than that I create a new list, to add to a new slide.

Also worth noting I am using CTTable, which you can get from a method in XSLFTable.